# Javascript Mouse tracking variable not switching from false to true

Tags: javascript

I am making a pretty simple game demo as part of my senior project, in which I'm trying to make a basic matching game that can help teach some basic mathematical skills. I would like to have the player be able to flip over cards to check if they have the right answer, however, the variable I am using to track whether or not the mouse is being clicked doesn't seem to ever register as true.

```
var isMouseDown = false;
c.onmousedown = 
function(evt) { isMouseDown = true; };
c.onmouseup = 
function(evt) { isMouseDown = false; };

// Keep track of where the mouse is
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
c.onmousemove = 
function(evt) {
    mouse.x = evt.clientX;
    mouse.y = evt.clientY;
};
```

This is where I use the variable:

```
this.clicked = function() {
    c.strokeRect(500, 500, 20, 20);
    if (isMouseDown) {
        c.strokeRect(400, 400, 20, 20);
        var diffX = mouse.x - this.x;
        var diffY = mouse.y - this.y;
        if (0 <= diffX <= 40) {
            var xInRange = true;
        } else {
            xInRange = false;
        }
        if (0<= diffY <= 60) {
            var yInRange = true;
            c.strokeRect(this.x + 10, this.y + 25, 20, 20);
        } else {
            yInRange = false;
        }
        if (xInRange && yInRange) {
            this.flip();
        }
    }
};
```

I have thrown in a few instructions for the canvas to build a box to see if it is compiling that part of the code, and it looks like the first one is being drawn when I run the program, but the second one (the one in the if statement) isn't, so I figured that would be where I'm running into a problem.

EDIT: Here is where I call on the function (this isn't finished, so there's a few pieces of code lying around unused):

```
    var cmTID;
    var timeStep = 50; //milliseconds
    var numCards = 10;
    function update() {
        var card = new Card(10, 10, 60, 40, 5);
        card.draw();
        card.clicked();//nothing after this compiles atm
        c.strokeRect(200, 200, 30, 30);
        clearTimeout(cmTID);
        cmTID = setTimeout(update, timeStep);
}
```

I don't have a ton of experience in Javascript, though I have done a fair amount of work in Java for AP Computer Science, which I took my sophomore year. And if you are wondering, yes, I bit off a *little* more than I could chew here :P

Can anyone give me pointers on what might be going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: it could be a scope problem. Hard to tell without the overview of how all this articulates.

Comment: I would use the debugger and step through your `clicked` function. Chances are, one of the values isn't what you expect.

Comment: how do you call the `clicked` function ? or is that supposed to be an event handler. In that case shouldn't it be `this.onclick = function..` ? Its named implies that it is fired after the click is completed and in some contexts that means after the `mouseup` has also occured.

Comment: what is the variable "c"?

Comment: "c' is the canvas. I could try making it an event handler, see how that works... Currently I am calling it in another function I am using to update the game. I'll update my post to include that. I have tried stepping through the function, but unfortunately that is as far as the compiler I use (the one that is built into Notepad++) gets. Which is why I put in the c.strokeRect's, to determine exactly where the problem is. Does anyone have any suggestions for a more sophisticated debugger I can use? Thanks for all of the feedback btw :)

Comment: isn't `c` the context?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to add `mouse` events to the context `c`. Instead add it to the actual `canvas` element.